# полное совпадение слов в строке

Tags: строки

Есть строка "минимализм, современный, классика"
Человек вводит слово, нужно найти совпадения в строке.
Есть куча способов, типа

```
if (preg_match("/$arr[$i]/", $string)) {
echo 'Слово ' . $arr[$i] . ' найдено в строке';}
```

и тому подобные.
Но положительный результат будет даже при вводе "минима" или "совре"
а мне нужно 100% совпадение.
Подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'привет меня зовут Крокодил Гена, я потерял чебурашку';
$string = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);
$arr = array('Гена', 'потерял');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (in_array($arr[$i], $string)) 
    echo 'Слово ' . $arr[$i] . ' найдено в строке';
}
```

нашел в инете